# Audio played back in android Webrtc

Tags: android, webrtc, voip, simplewebrtc

Hey Android webrtc peeps. 
I am working on android webrtc audio calling and the audio quality seems to be great. I have managed to somehow eliminate the echo using AEC.

However, sometimes I hear my voice being played back to me and I have no idea how to solve this.

Any help please?

Comment: Important note: If one party uses an earpiece, the playback stops

Comment: You can try to play with media constraints to get the best results, the list of constraints could be found here https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/app/webrtc/mediaconstraintsinterface.cc